# render partial :object vs :locals

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= render :partial => 'partial/path', :locals => {:xyz => 'abc'} %>
```

vs

```
<%= render :partial => 'partial/path', :object => @some_object %>
```

I think the first one make a local variable named `xyz` available in the partial and the second one makes a local variable named `object` available in the partial. So what is the difference? (Besides `locals` allows more than one variable)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the second case using :object will define a variable with the same name as the partial by default.  If my partial template is named _user.html.erb then there will be a local variable named "user" defined in the template.

You can specify a different variable name with :as => "another_name".

This is documented here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html , here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/PartialRenderer

...and for older Rails (version <= v3.09):
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Partials

Comment: Documentation moved here:
[http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)

Answer (score 62):

The second form

```
render :partial => 'account', :object => @some_account
```

will make sure the `account` variable in the partial will be set to `@some_account`.
You can rename the variable using the `:as` option.

The biggest advantage of the `:locals` is that

- you have very clear control over the objects and names
- you can assign more than 1 variable

So you could do something like

```
render partial => 'some_view', :locals => { :user => account.user, :details => some_details_we_retrieved }
```

making a clear seperation possible when needed.

The disadvantage of the `:locals` approach is that it is more verbose, and sometimes a simple

```
render :partial => 'account'
```

is identical to

```
render :partial => 'account', :locals => {:account => @account }
```

So use the one which suits you the best (or where it suits the best).

Comment: I have an example where I can access the name of the :object variable via object in my partial... Which is strange.

Comment: If `@account` is nil, `:object=>@account` will not make account available in the partial; you'll get an error trying to do something like this: `if account <do something>`. If you're not sure whether @account has been defined, use  `:locals => { :account=>@account }`

Answer (score 21):

If you're using Rails 3+, there's an even easier syntax to use:

```
# Instead of <%= render partial: "account", locals: { account: @buyer } %>
<%= render 'account', account: @buyer %>
```

Source: [Action View Partials](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)

Comment: FYI, if you're trying to render a partial from a controller, this short form **will not work**.

Comment: When I read the above comment I asked myself, "so what DOES work from a controller?" At the risk of stating the obvious, the answer is the version that includes the `locals:` key.