# How can I pass more than 2 arguments to partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to pass 2 arguments such as `topic` and `icon_photo`.
How can I do that?

> undefined method `icon_photo?'

I got this error with the code below.

**view**

```
<div class="Topic">
  <% @community.topics.each do |topic| %>
    <%= render 'topics/topic', :topic => topic, :icon_photo => topic.user.profile.avatar %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass a locals hash:

```
<div class="Topic">
  <% @community.topics.each do |topic| %>
    <%= render 'topics/topic', locals: {topic: topic, icon_photo: topic.user.profile.avatar, etc: 'blabla' } %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

See some **documentation** here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-render.htm

**A little improvement** can be mabe, you can render your collection like this:

```
<div class="Topic">
  <%= render partial: 'topics/topic', collection: @community.topics %>
</div>


# in your partial topics/_topic.html.erb:
<% icon_photo = topic.user.profile.avatar %>
```

Comment: It's so weird I still get this error `undefined method 'icon_photo?' for #<#<Class:0x00000012eb9fd0>:0x000000125d4168>` which is this `<% if icon_photo? %>`

Comment: The variable you pass is `icon_photo` without the '?' at the end. Test it like this: `if icon_photo.present?`

Comment: Can you see what's the problem?

Comment: undefined local variable or method `icon_photo'

Comment: maybe `if !icon_photo.nil?

Comment: It just keeps saying `undefined local variable or method 'icon_photo' fo`

Comment: in your partial view '/topics/topic.html.erb' are you sure you are using `icon_photo` variable AND passed it to your partial like: `render 'topics/topic', :locals => {topic: topic, :icon_photo => topic.user.profile.avatar}` ?

Comment: You know what. Even I just did  `:locals => {:topic => topic }` it says undefined local variable or method error.

Comment: And also, the variable icon_photo is also accessible via your partial view since you pass the topic object. In your partial view you can retrieve the icon_photo by doing `topic.user.profile.avatar`

Comment: I don't think so. Because If I take `:locals => {}` off, now it starts working again as long as it's single argument

Comment: partial will be accessible from everywhere, that's why I'm trying to pass argument:)

Comment: It should be working with Rails 3. I have this everywhere in my projects.

Comment: I'm using 3.2.11 the latest one

Comment: Try this: `render 'topics/topic', {:topic => topic, :icon_photo => topic.user.profile.avatar}`

Comment: Look, it should be working fine for you if everything is declared properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122223/render-partial-object-vs-locals