# Unhappy with the rail way of rendering partials

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, renderpartial

my question considers the partial handling in Rails. I just can't get the reason for some design decisions.

If I render a partial like this:

```
<%= render partial: 'foo/bar', object: @herbie %>
```

Where @herbie is an object of class Car. Why is the local variable called `bar` by default instead of `car` which - at least for me - would be more reasonable in most cases.

If various partials share a common layout I have to add the `layout: ...` each time I use `render partial:`. This seems odd to me! Isn't it more likely to have various partials wich share the same layout then the other way around? Wouldn't it be more reasonable to define the layout within the partial, or to add a `to_layout_path` method to the ActiveRecord Model?

*Update:*

I get the point that it might be better to use the partial name, as this is well known in the partial context. However the use of the tags :locals and :as screws up this argumentation.

In an actual case I want to use different partials depending on the state of an object (questions that could be open or closed). I moved the decision which partial to render to the `Question.to_partial_path` method which seems to be quite elegant. However I named the partials `open_question` and `closed_question` and this makes the partial code unreadable. 
It gets even worse if I consider different types of questions.

I expect that within a partial we always make some presumptions about the model that is passed in. Thus in `closed_question` I am quit sure that I get a question - thus I would expect the variable to be called question. On the other hand I can imagine situations where we pass in something different that just behaves appropriated (Duck-typing).

My temporal meaning about partials is that within the partial it should be possible to define the name of the given parameter as well as a layout file that is used. 
The parameter indeed can be realized by introducing a new variable ( question = open_question) which feels a little bit unclean to me.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass in an argument to a method there's no way of knowing what the "name" of that variable is. The only thing the partial rendering method here has at its disposal is the `foo/bar` name, the `object` attribute, and some model.

That your model originated in a variable called `@car` is completely lost in the process of making the call.

It's convention in Rails that the variable used within the partial is the same as the name of the partial itself. You can override this if you want to have non-standard behaviour:

```
render(partial: 'foo/bar', locals: { car: @car })
```

As a note, though, going down the non-standard path is usually a bad idea. Whenever possible, just rename your partial to better match your expectations.

Comment: Thank you for this first request. It made me rethink it. I edit my question. Your "solution" using `:locals` also ends up in not knowing the name of the local variable. Maybe the variable should just be `object` for any partial.

Comment: The keys of the `locals` hash are used to establish the name of the locals. You have to repeat it, as I have here with `car: @car` or `foo: @foo`.

Comment: Sorry if my english is not understandable ;-) I referred to the fact that the local variables are not declared within the partial but during the render call and thus are 'unknown' while writing the partial.

Comment: Each partial has to be constructed according to how it's called, so you need to be extra careful here. You need to design your partial, then call it correctly or there will be errors about undefined variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is related: [render partial :object vs :locals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122223/render-partial-object-vs-locals)

The documentation is pretty good: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html

The default is to name the object after the partial.  If you want to be explicit, you can use :as or locals.

```
render partial: 'foo/bar', locals: {car: @car}
render partial: 'foo/bar', object: @car, as: 'car'
```

Comment: I am not asking for a solution but tried to understand the logic behind the rails design-decision. I am aware of these parameters and I already read the above links. However I did not get the point why it is as it is!