# Rails 4 params not being sent to the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I have been battling with what is going to turn out to be a quick answer for someone...

I have view with nested partials. The index has a partial to the categories which has a partial to the subcategories.

The categories are looping as expected but for some reason the locals don't seem to be reaching the controller.

My code is as follows:

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: "categories/categories", object: @categories %>
```

**_categories.html.erb**

```
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
        <% if category.category_parent == 0 %>
            <li><a href=""><%= category.category_name %> <i class="icons icon-right-dir"></i></a>
                <%= render partial: "categories/subcategories", object: @subcategories, locals: {parent_id: category.category_id} %>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

**_subcategories.html.erb**

```
      <% if @parent != nil %>
      <ul class="sidebar-dropdown">
        <li>
          <ul>
            <% @subcategories.each do |subcategory| %>
              <li><a href=""><%= subcategory.category_name %> <i class="icons icon-right-dir"></i></a></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <% end %>
```

**categories_controller.rb**

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :categories, :subcategories

  def categories
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def subcategories
    @parent = params[:parent_id]
    @subcategories = Category.where(:category_parent => params[:parent_id])
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

`@categories` is an instance variables, and you shouldn't need to pass it from view to view. So the first render statment becomes:

```
<%= render "categories/categories" %>
```

(I'm more familiar leaving off `partial:`)

**_categories.html.erb** becomes this:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <% if category.category_parent == 0 %>
    <li><a href=""><%= category.category_name %> <i class="icons icon-right-dir"></i></a>
      <%= render "categories/subcategories", category: category %>
      <%# Note passing in category to have access to it as a local %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**_subcategories.html.erb**

```
<% if category != nil %>
  <ul class="sidebar-dropdown">
    <li>
      <ul>
        <% category.subcategories.each do |subcategory| %>
          <li><a href=""><%= subcategory.category_name %> <i class="icons icon-right-dir"></i></a></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

I don't think you should be looking up `@subcategories` in your controller. It looks like in `def categories` you're just getting all the categories and then looping through them in the view. As it is, this will be n+1, as every time it loops over a new category, it will have to do a db query to find its subcategories. You can avoid this with includes.

**categories_contorller.rb**

```
def categories
  @categories = Category.all.includes(:subcategories)
end
```

This is what I think is simplest and clearest. But I also haven't played with `object:` too much. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122223/render-partial-object-vs-locals) might help you if you want to stick to that pattern:

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and the link to the post.

Comment: I am getting a mongoid error around @categories = Category.all.includes(:subcategories). It says "Invalid includes directive"

Comment: Oh! Mongoid. Yeah, `.all` works differently now in ActiveRecord—probably not so in Mongoid. You should be able to just do: `Category.includes(:subcategories)`

Comment: It says the following:

Problem:
  Invalid includes directive: Category.includes(:subcategories)
Summary:
  Eager loading in Mongoid only supports providing arguments to Category.includes that are the names of relations on the Category model, and only supports one level of eager loading. (ie, eager loading associations not on the Category but one step away via another relation is not allowed.
Resolution:
  Ensure that each parameter passed to Category.includes is a valid name of a relation on the Category model. These are: .

Comment: First, try it without the includes to make sure it works. The includes is just to improve performance anyway. Assuming it works, what's the relationship between Category and Subcategory? If it's `has_many` then I think it should work just like ActiveRecord (with which I'm more familiar). If it's `embeds_many`, then includes probably isn't even necessary.